# What to do for API versions without View.setX?

Tags: android, android-widget

So, much to my chagrin, I found out while testing on an earlier device, that pre-API version 11, the View class has no setAlpha nor setX methods. Can someone suggest an alternative? I'm currently moving a view around by updating its X location, and fading it in and out based on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You may use standard `Animation` to implement such program logic, such as `AlphaAnimation` and `TranslateAnimation` to make movement of your `View`. But also you should keep in mind that original position of `View` at it's parent layout isn't changed (only **pixels are redrawn**). That means, that when user would taps on new image of `View`, this `View` would not get event, as it's `Rect` remains in the old position.

You could relocate `View`s rectangle after the end of animation, using `View.layout()` method with 4 positioning parameters passed there, but in this case you should consider about your layout nature, because for example if you work with `LinearLayout` and change the position of it sibling by calling `layout()` method, next change of one of UI elements size will call `reaqestLayout()` method and your animated `View` will come back at it's initial position